# Set SQLAlchemy default options for relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to provide default options for relationship definitions (and maybe other constructs, like Session). I'm building a JSON API and would like to have all relationships defined as lazy='dynamic', since I need to allow further filtering for most of them.

E.g. when I define Client model as:

```
class Client(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'client'

    query        = Session.query_property()
    id           = Column(Integer, nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    transactions = relationship('Transaction', back_populates = 'client',
                                               order_by = 'Transaction.id',
                                               lazy = 'dynamic')
```

I can then filter transactions using

```
client = Client.query.first()
client.transactions.filter_by(**conditions).all()
```

where conditions is a dict of attribute values. Is there a way to make lazy='dynamic' default?

Answer (score 0):

Write another function `lazy_relationship` that returns `relationship` with the arguments passed to it, plus the `lazy=True` argument.

Here's a simple example:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

def lazy_relationship(*args, **kwargs):
    return relationship(*args, lazy='dynamic', **kwargs)
```

In production, you might also check whether `lazy=True` is passed as an argument to `lazy_relationship`, and handle the case when it is before returning `relationship`.

This approach can be extended to create a general utility function, that can be used elsewhere in the project:

**update: added some code to illustrate how this is generalized**

```
def set_defaults(func, default_value_dict):
    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(default_value_dict)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return helper

lazy_relationship = set_defaults(relationship, {'lazy': 'dynamic'})
# then you can call `lazy_relationship` as you'd call `relationship`.
```

Comment: Thanks, this would of course work. I was just interested if there's some generic way to provide default options, since there may be a lot of different options to be defaulted.

Comment: please see updated answer. this is a pretty general solution that would allow you to update default values passed to functions. note that if you're passing objects as parameters, you may have to use copy.deepcopy instead of simply calling dictionary update method.

Comment: oh, this is a great solution, I love it, thanks a lot. and higher order functions be blessed.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with overriding `relationship` with `partial(relationship, lazy='dynamic')` ( use partial function from functools module )

It raised an error if relationship is one-to-one or many-to-one.

It might be better if defining new relationship name for example

`has_many = partial(relationship, lazy='dynamic')`

and the use as needed